# Navigate from one screen to another, half screen load and take a moment then load full screen page (half black / white screen page)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have two pages, at first page there are some controls( textbox, button). when I enter some text it goes to second page then load the data from api(web service), but at this page screen load half and wait a moment then load full screen after that showing the data.

Comment: Can you make some screenshots to see what is wrong ?

Comment: Also put your code for second view. So we can get idea what is the issue.

Comment: Try to send navigation in Deployment.Current.Dispatecher..

Comment: Also try to give a default Height & Width to you pages eg 800 x 480.

Comment: share your code. then only i can able to help you.

Comment: I'm guessing you're blocking the UI thread but without being able to see what you're doing we can but guess.

Comment: Hi Aliassse : here is the screen shot [link](http://sdrv.ms/160dCvx) please check

Comment: Nirmit and Mohamed Thaufeeq, here I am sharing my code snipped and fact those I found till : 
At second page I am sending a url to a method which is define in another class and that return result as I expect.

Method is given below which fetch the result:

Comment: public static async Task<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> DataMethod(string url, string operation, string _word)
{
string result = "";  
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
var factory = new TaskFactory();
var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(req.BeginGetResponse, req.EndGetResponse, null);
var res = await task;
Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{result = reader.ReadToEnd();}
stream.Close();
/*some more code but not useful so I hide that*/
}

Comment: when I debug the code, I found that black/white screen freeze until the following(two lines code) code is not executed 
"
var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(req.BeginGetResponse, req.EndGetResponse, null);
var res = await task;
"
Thanks